# How can I resolve a hostname to an IP address in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, dns

What's the most concise way to resolve a hostname to an IP address in a Bash script? I'm using [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux).

Comment: Shame that the `getent <ahosts|ahostsv4|ahostsv6|hosts> <hostname>` answer is somewhere down there near the bottom. It's the simplest, requires no extra packages and is *easier* to parse from a Bash script, too.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: The new shame is that that answer suggests `getent hosts somehost`, when [running this *while on `somehost`* will produce an IPv6 address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50417/252466), which is different from how most other tools (`ping`, `ssh` at least) resolve names, and breaks some things.  Use the `ahosts` instead of `hosts`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: who keeps you from requesting specifically IPv4 (`ahostsv4`)  _or_ IPv6 (`ahostsv6`) addresses? Personally I find nothing wrong with the unspecific request returning IPv6. Your code should be prepared. IPv6 has been out there for more than 20 years now.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Nobody "keeps me" from doing that, but the answer specifically suggests `hosts`, and so far 4 people have upvoted vinc17's comment expressing the pain caused by "suddenly IPv6".  Being prepared for IPv6 is not always the issue: many programs need a way to determine whether two names/addresses refer to the same host.  They can either use simple string matching, or they must know a lot about the network to find the "true" answer.  The latter is a minefield, so many 3rd-party programs and systems -- that I have no control over -- use the former.

Answer (score 818, accepted):

You can use `getent`, which comes with `glibc` (so you almost certainly have it on Linux). This resolves using gethostbyaddr/gethostbyname2, and so also will check `/etc/hosts`/NIS/etc:

```
getent hosts unix.stackexchange.com | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Or, as Heinzi said below, you can use `dig` with the `+short` argument (queries DNS servers directly, does not look at `/etc/hosts`/NSS/etc) :

```
dig +short unix.stackexchange.com
```

If `dig +short` is unavailable, any one of the following should work. All of these query DNS directly and ignore other means of resolution:

```
host unix.stackexchange.com | awk '/has address/ { print $4 }'
nslookup unix.stackexchange.com | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }'
dig unix.stackexchange.com | awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:$/ { getline ; print $5 }'
```

If you want to only print one IP, then add the `exit` command to `awk`'s workflow.

```
dig +short unix.stackexchange.com | awk '{ print ; exit }'
getent hosts unix.stackexchange.com | awk '{ print $1 ; exit }'
host unix.stackexchange.com | awk '/has address/ { print $4 ; exit }'
nslookup unix.stackexchange.com | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 ; exit }'
dig unix.stackexchange.com | awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:$/ { getline ; print $5 ; exit }'
```

Comment: By default, using dig only works with ipv4, where host gives both ipv4 and ipv6 answers.  This might be unexpected.  You can try `host www.google.com`, `dig +short www.google.com`, `host ipv6.google.com`, `dig +short ipv6.google.com`, `host www.facebook.com`, `dig +short www.facebook.com`.

Comment: Also note that you may want to use `dig +search` if you want to reproduce `host` command more closely

Comment: DIG does not work, if is a CNAME it will not return the IP.

Comment: Sometimes, `host` can be timed out and returns nothing. For some domains, `dig +short` may return domain alias in the first line. So, to ensure the output is an IPv4 address, use `dig +short example.com | grep -Eo '[0-9\.]{7,15}' | head -1`.

Comment: When I `dig` with an `http` protocol added, it finds `SOA`. When I `dig` without the `http` protocol, it comes with the A record. What does this mean? Why does dig change depending on http protocol?

Comment: `host` prints error output to `stdout`, `dig` also seems to return `0` for unresolved hosts, `getent` doesn't seem to allow a timeout... I'm surprised this is so complicated.

Comment: In the case where `host.domain.com` is a CNAME record, I found that `dig +short host.domain.com` will return the referenced DNS name instead of the IP address, whereas `getent hosts host.domain.com` will always return the IP address.

Comment: There's a big difference between "ask the OS to resolve a host" and "run this program which will use its internal logic to query DNS". I'm fairly sure that nslookup & dig are in the latter category, though I don't know about 'host'. For example, what if the host is defined in /etc/hosts?

Comment: @tomwhipple For the purposes of this question, the distinction seems not particularly important. However, I will separate this answer out to differentiate functions using the OS resolver vs. their own means.

Comment: Using `getent hosts <host>` is incorrect, as for instance it may give an IPv6 address while IPv6 doesn't work. The correct solution is to use `getent ahosts <host>` to try both IPv6 and IPv4 if needed.

Comment: Worth mentioning: host, dig and nslookup seems to directly talk to the servers listed in resolv.conf, whereas "getent hosts" respect both the local hosts file and library-level caching (such as nscd) if enabled.

Comment: `dig +short unix.stackexchange.com | awk '/^[0-9]+\./ { print ; exit }'` considers CNAMEs.

Comment: I can resolv avahi-hosts by using getent method (only this method)

Comment: You can use `$(dig +short example.com | tail -1)` to only take the last line of output of the command (in my testing it has always been an IP address and never a hostname, but I think this shouldn't be relied upon).  Going the other way, for more robust checking for IPv4 address, you can build upon luissquall's awk command. I'm aware I'm being a bit pedantic, but that one only checks the first character.  This checks whole lines: `awk '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/ { print ; exit }`  ... Match 1 to 3 digits followed by a dot, all that three times, then 1 to 3 digits, with nothing else after.

Comment: Downside of using `getent hosts` is lack of control getting just IPv4 or just IPv6.

Comment: @JohnGreene, you can ask for one or the other specifically with the `ahostsv4` and `ahostsv6` except the output is a bit more complex then; see the other answer.

Answer (score 171):

With `host` from the [dnsutils](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/dnsutils/) package:

```
$ host unix.stackexchange.com
unix.stackexchange.com has address 64.34.119.12
```

(**Corrected** package name according to the comments. As a note other distributions have `host` in different packages: Debian/Ubuntu *bind9-host*, openSUSE *bind-utils*, Frugalware *bind*.)

Comment: See the resolveip entry below if you need to resolve something not in DNS (e.g. /etc/hosts)

Comment: Be aware that `host` sometimes returns multi-line output (in the case of redirects), you'll want `host unix.stackexchange.com | tail -n1` if you just want the line with the IP address.

Comment: There are multiple versions of "host" with different output formats. E.g. most systems seem to have the BIND9 version, but my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server has some completely different version somehow..

Comment: if you don't have `host` or `dig` installed you can use ping instead which is always available:
`ping unix.stackexchange.com -c 1 -q 2>&1 | grep -Po "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}"`
this does not need any extra packages install on most Unix/Linux matchines.

Comment: This answer deserves a serious downvote. `host` is a DNS tool (similar to `nslookup`) so it only looks up hosts in DNS, not in e.g. `/etc/hosts`. So it is **NOT** an answer to OP's question.

Comment: `host` can also return stale IP data.

Comment: Often doesn't work, despite an /etc/hosts entry being available.

Answer (score 60):

I have a tool on my machine that seems to do the job. The man page shows it seems to come with mysql... Here is how you could use it:

```
resolveip -s unix.stackexchange.com
64.34.119.12
```

The return value of this tool is different from 0 if the hostname cannot be resolved :

```
resolveip -s unix.stackexchange.coma
resolveip: Unable to find hostid for 'unix.stackexchange.coma': host not found
exit 2
```

**UPDATE**
On fedora, it comes with mysql-server :

```
yum provides "*/resolveip"
mysql-server-5.5.10-2.fc15.x86_64 : The MySQL server and related files
Dépôt         : fedora
Correspondance depuis :
Nom de fichier      : /usr/bin/resolveip
```

I guess it would create a strange dependency for your script...

Comment: This seems to be the only solution on here that uses the OS's build in resolver - so works for /etc/hosts as well as DNS.

Comment: `getent`, as detailed in the other answer, also looks at /etc/hosts, and comes with glibc, so has no dependencies on a Linux system.

Comment: I would not use resolveip since you create a dependency on another package.  getent is installed by default.  host, nslookup, and dig are all in optional packages.  Definitely use getent in a script.

Comment: i like this answer but it doesn't return ipv6

Comment: > pacman -Qo /bin/resolveip
/usr/bin/resolveip is owned by mariadb 10.5.9-1

Answer (score 59):

The following command using `dig` allows you to read the result directly without any sed/awk/etc. magic:

```
$ dig +short unix.stackexchange.com
64.34.119.12
```

`dig` is also included in the `dnsutils` package.

---

**Note**: `dig` has a return value of `0`, even if the name could not be resolved. Thus, you'd need to check if the output is empty instead of checking the return value:

```
hostname=unix.stackexchange.com

ip=`dig +short $hostname`

if [ -n "$ip" ]; then
    echo IP: $ip
else
    echo Could not resolve hostname.
fi
```

---

**Note 2**: If a hostname has multiple IP addresses (try `debian.org`, for example), all of them will be returned. This "problem" affects all of the tools mentioned in this question so far:

Comment: Note that if a domain has a CNAME entry its domain may be printed in the first line instead of an IP address.

Comment: dig doesn't work when DNS is not configured, or when the host has no DNS server entry but exists in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 53):

```
getent hosts unix.stackexchange.com | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: Also consider `ahosts`, `ahostsv4`, `ahostsv6` with `getent`.

Comment: `cut` will not for getent's, which use `\t` to separate columns. This is the case on Solaris.

Comment: @ceving: On Solaris you might have to run `cut` without `-d` (defaults to `\t` as delimiter ). On Linux it's spaces, thus the line above works.

Answer (score 34):

Simple but useful:

1. `getent ahostsv4 www.google.de | grep STREAM | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
2. `getent ahostsv6 www.google.de | grep STREAM | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
3. `getent hosts google.de | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

All commands will resolve an IP address if the host still exists. If the host points to a CNAME it will also get the IP in that case.

The first command returns the resolved IPv4 address.

The second command returns the resolved IPv6 address.

The third command will return the owner's preferred address, which may either an IPv4 or an IPv6 address.

Comment: By far the most simple one. And its avilable by default. Not like `host` that require install of the `bindutils`

Comment: Use `awk '{ print $1 ; exit }'` instead of `head` and `cut`

Answer (score 33):

The solutions given so far mostly work in the simpler case: the hostname directly resolves to a single IPv4 address.  This might be the only case where you need to resolve hostnames, but if not, below is a discussion on some cases that you might need to handle.

Chris Down and Heinzi briefly discussed the case where the hostname resolves to more than one IP addresses.  In this case (and others below), basic scripting under the assumption that a hostname directly resolves to a single IP address may break.  Below, an example with a hostname resolving to more than a single IP address:

```
$ host www.l.google.com
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.148.147
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.148.103
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.148.99
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.148.106
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.148.105
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.148.104
```

But what is `www.l.google.com`?  This is where the **alias** case needs to be introduced.  Let's check the example below:

```
$ host www.google.com
www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.103
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.147
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.105
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.99
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.106
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.104
```

So `www.google.com` does not directly resolve to IP addresses, but to an alias that itself resolves to multiple IP addresses.  For more information on aliases, check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record).  Of course, the case where an alias has a single IP address is possible, as shown below:

```
$ host g.www.ms.akadns.net
g.www.ms.akadns.net is an alias for lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.
lb1.www.ms.akadns.net has address 207.46.19.190
```

But can aliases be chained?  The answer is yes:

```
$ host www.microsoft.com
www.microsoft.com is an alias for toggle.www.ms.akadns.net.
toggle.www.ms.akadns.net is an alias for g.www.ms.akadns.net.
g.www.ms.akadns.net is an alias for lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.
lb1.www.ms.akadns.net has address 207.46.19.254

$ host www.google.fr
www.google.fr is an alias for www.google.com.
www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.147
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.103
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.99
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.106
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.104
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.39.105
```

I did not find any example where a hostname resolves to an alias that does not resolve to an IP address, but I think the case might occur.

More than multiple IP addresses and aliases, is there some other special cases... what about IPv6?  You could try:

```
$ host ipv6.google.com
ipv6.google.com is an alias for ipv6.l.google.com.
ipv6.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:8007::68
```

Where the hostname `ipv6.google.com` is an IPv6-only hostname.  What about dual-stack hostnames:

```
$ host www.facebook.com
www.facebook.com has address 66.220.153.15
www.facebook.com has IPv6 address 2620:0:1c08:4000:face:b00c::
```

Again about IPv6, if your host is IPv4 only, you can still resolve IPv6 addresses (tested on a IPv4 only WinXP and with ipv6.google.com, you could try it on Linux).  In this case, the resolution succeeds, but a ping fails with an *unknown host error message*.  This might be a case where your scripting fails.

I hope those remarks were useful.

Comment: What a great complement to the accepted answer, showing all the edge cases that one might want to deal with in scripting. My version `host` does not even state "has address" for my boxes.

Answer (score 25):

To avoid the problem with aliases and always get a single IP address ready for use:

```
python -c 'import socket; print socket.gethostbyname("www.example.com")'
```

Comment: I made a bash function to stick in my bashrc from this answer: https://gist.github.com/brycepg/ba117a37de53906dc8fcc312bd7d5fee

Comment: `python3 -c 'import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname("www.example.com"))'`

Comment: awesome tip. As far as I can see this is the only one that also will work on my mac and my windows machines

Answer (score 24):

```
ping -q -c 1 -t 1 your_host_here | grep PING | sed -e "s/).*//" | sed -e "s/.*(//"
```

works without dependencies on other systems (and for hosts specified in /etc/hosts)

Comment: The use of ping is what I needed as I need the value from the hosts file but the sed pattern parsing correctly but this worked
    ping -q -c 1 -t 1 your_host_here | grep PING | sed -e "s/^[^(]*[(]//" | sed -e "s/[)].*$//"

Comment: To resolve something on my home network like myhostname.local this works so for me this is the best answer.

Comment: May I suggest this also: `ping -q -c 1 -t 1 bahface.local | grep -m 1 PING | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1`

Comment: `getent <ahosts|ahostsv4|ahostsv6|hosts> <hostname>` works for declarations inside `/etc/hosts`, too ... and it's *the* go-to-tool for all kinds of system databases (passwd, group, aliases, services).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a slight variation of the `ping` approach that takes "unknown host" into account (by piping through stderr) and uses `tr` to avoid the use of `sed` regexps:

```
ping -c1 -t1 -W0 www.example.com 2>&1 | tr -d '():' | awk '/^PING/{print $3}'
```

In case it's important to capture the exit value, then the following will work (although less elegant):

```
ping -c1 -t1 -W0 www.example.com &>/dev/null && ping -c1 -t1 -W0 www.example.com 2>&1 | tr -d '():' | awk '/^PING/{print $3}'
```

Comment: I love this solution, because it works without any extra tools.

Answer (score 8):

To complete Chris Down's answer, and address jfgagne comments about (possibly chained) aliases, here is a solution that :

- takes into account multiple IPs
- takes into account one or more aliases (CNAME)
- does not query `/etc/hosts` file (in my case I didn't want it); to query it, dbernt's python solution is perfect)
- does not use awk/sed

  ```
  dig +short www.alias.com  | grep -v "\.$" | head -n 1
  ```

Always returns the first IP address, or empty tring if not resolved. with version of dig :

```
    $ dig -v
    DiG 9.8.1-P1
```

Comment: Thanks, other answers assume "dig +short" *always* returns a single ip address. They weren't accounting for CNAMEs.

Answer (score 6):

here's a Bash recipe I cooked up using other folk's answers — first tries `/etc/hosts`, then falls back to nslookup:

```bsh
resolveip(){
    local host="$1"
    if [ -z "$host" ]
    then
        return 1
    else
        local ip=$( getent hosts "$host" | awk '{print $1}' )
        if [ -z "$ip" ] 
        then
            ip=$( dig +short "$host" )
            if [ -z "$ip" ]
            then
                echo "unable to resolve '$host'" >&2 
                return 1
            else
                echo "$ip"
                return 0
            fi
        else
            echo "$ip"
            return 0
        fi
    fi
}
```

Comment: To be clear, `getent hosts` isn't just a lookup in /etc/hosts - it's a full-on DNS-resolving call to [gethostbyaddr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyaddr.3.html), and it's *very* unlikely to fail in a case where `dig` will succeed. See [the man page for getent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html).

Comment: @Stuart is right — i've learned a great deal since writing that and oversimplified a powerful command. `getent` remains my favorite, although i also like `dig +short`

Answer (score 6):

```
 php -r "echo gethostbyname('unix.stackexchange.com');"
```

Comment: this works, but it requires that php is installed on your terminal

Comment: can be useful on a typical php docker container where "host", "dig" etc. are not available

Comment: `php -r 'echo gethostbyname($argv[1]);' google.com`

Answer (score 6):

```
nmap -sP 192.168.178.0/24|grep YOUR_HOSTNAME|sed -n 's/.*[(]\([0-9\.]*\)[)].*/\1/p'
```

was the solution I found without DNS server

Answer (score 6):

I would have liked to add this as a comment to Andrew McGregor Re: ping. However it wouldn't let me, so I need to add this as another answer. (If somebody can move it into a comment, feel free to.)

This is another variant, only using ping and grep:

```
ping -q -c1 -t1 your_host_here | grep -Eo "([0-9]+\.?){4}"
```

`grep -E` for extended regular expression and
`grep -o` to return only the matching part.
the regexp itself looks for one or multiple digits (`[0-9]+`) and optionally a dot (`\.?`) four times (`{4}`)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `host`:

```
hostname=example.org

# strips the IP
IP=$( host ${hostname} | sed -e "s/.*\ //" )

# checks for errors
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo "Error: cannot resolve ${hostname}" 1>&2
   exit 1;
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

```bsh
dig  +noall +answer +nocomments example.com | awk '{printf "%-36s\t%s\n", $1, $5 }'
```

Comment: Some context in what way that answer improves over the already existing ones would be great. Also, please indent commands by 4 spaces (cf. the markdown syntax).

Answer (score 5):

dig is too slow, nslookup is much faster

```
nslookup google.com | grep -Po 'Address:\s*[0-9.]+' | tail -1 | sed -e 's/Address:\s*//g'
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the most concise, but it seems to be robust and efficient:

```
# $(get_host_dns_short "google.com")
#
# Outputs the IPv4 IP Address of a hostname, resolved by DNS. Returns 0 if DNS
# responded successfully; 1 otherwise. Will mask error output.
function get_host_dns_short()
{
    (
        set -o pipefail

        host -4 -W1 -t A "$1" 2>/dev/null | awk '/has address/ { print $NF; exit }'
    ) && return 0 || return 1
}
```

This will output a single IPv4 IP, as well as return `1` in the event of failure, while masking stderr output.

You can use it like this:

```
GOOGLE_IP="$(get_host_dns_short "google.com")"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Google's IP is ${GOOGLE_IP}."
else
    echo "Failed to resolve Google's IP."
fi
```

> Google's IP is 216.58.192.46.

If you want an IPv6 address instead, just replace `-4` with `-6`.

Answer (score 4):

I am doing this all the time on my Mac which does not have `getent`. `ping` seems like a hack. I would like to take `/etc/hosts` into account as well.

So, I wrote a stupid wrapper for `dns.lookup` for you who have Node.js installed to provide a CLI:

```
$ npm install -g lookup-hostname
$ lookup google.com
62.243.192.89
```

Comment: 60% chance of breakage before you get anywhere near a resolve.

Comment: @dotbit could you elaborate? I've used this weekly since '17 and never had any issues.

Comment: @Jensen but you're the only one ever, as always. The rest of us usually run into FAIL of one sort or the other, and always.

Comment: _"as always"_ What do you mean by that?

_"The rest of us"_ Who's that?

_"run into FAIL"_ What specific issue are you seeing? I'm curious.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

systemd-resolve   RT.com -t A  | awk '{ print $4 ; exit }'
systemd-resolve unix.stackexchange.com -t A --legend=no | awk '{ print $4 ; exit }'

resolveip -s      RT.com
dig       +short  RT.com
host              RT.com | awk '/has address/ { print $4 }'
nslookup          RT.com | awk '/^Address: /  { print $2 }'
ping -q -c 1 -t 1 RT.com | grep PING | sed -e "s/).*//" | sed -e "s/.*(//"

ruby     -rresolv -e      ' print    Resolv.getaddress "RT.com" '
python2  -c 'import socket; print socket.gethostbyname("RT.com")'
perl     -MSocket -MNet::hostent -E 'say inet_ntoa((gethost shift)->addr)' RT.com  2>/dev/null
php      -r "echo gethostbyname( 'RT.com' );"

echo        "   all do work for me - take your pick!  "
```

Answer (score 3):

1 line resolve a list of hostname

```
for LINE in `cat ~/Desktop/mylist`; do a=$(nslookup $LINE | awk '/^Address: / { print $1 }');  echo $a >> ~/Desktop/ip; done
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the easiest way for a bash-script but if you want to resolve a hostname and see if the host is up, use `ping`!

```
ping -a hostname -c 1
```

Will `ping` the host one time and resolve the hostname to IP-address.

```
$ ping -a www.google.com -c 1
PING www.google.com (216.58.211.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from arn09s10-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.132): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=1.51 ms
```

Comment: using ping is good, because everybody has it, but you need to to filter the IP-Part from the outputs, if you like to use it in a script.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many answers already, but a solution using perl is missing:

```
perl -MSocket -MNet::hostent -E 'say inet_ntoa((gethost shift)->addr)' unix.stackexchange.com
```

In a bash script it could be used like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddr=$(perl -MSocket -MNet::hostent -E 'say inet_ntoa((gethost shift)->addr)' unix.stackexchange.com)
echo $ipaddr
```

Modules used here are core modules, so should be available everywhere without installing with CPAN.

Comment: `perl -MSocket -MNet::hostent -E 'say inet_ntoa((gethost shift)->addr)' unix.stackexchange.com  2>/dev/null`

is much cleaner. but no one but the two of us are using pörl , everyone else uses Pascal Script of course.

Comment: Actually I prefer to see the error messages if anything goes wrong. `Can't call method "addr" on an undefined value` isn't exactly the best error message, but may give a hint about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A python3 based variant that displays all ipv4 and ipv6 addresses from the system dns resolver, each ip as a separate line:

```
python3 -c 'import socket, sys; print("\n".join([x[4][0] for x in socket.getaddrinfo(sys.argv[1], 0, type=socket.SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM)]))' example.com
```

If sensible error handling is needed this would need an additional try: block etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
host -t a cisco.com
```

this command will show ip address ( will reslove domain to IP )

Answer (score -1):

Besides above solution, you can translate multiple host name to ip via below script, the only dependency is "ping" command in core Unix:

```
getip(){ ping -c 1 -t 1 $1 | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | tr -d '()' 2>&1 | tee >> /tmp/result.log & }

getip 'hostname.number1.net'

getip 'hostname.number2.net'

getip 'hostname.number3.net'

getip 'hostname.number4.net'

getip 'hostname.number5.net'

getip 'hostname.number6.net'

getip 'hostname.number7.net'

getip 'hostname.number8.net'
```

```
$ cat /tmp/result.log

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY1

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY2

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY3

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY4

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY5

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY6

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY7

ABC.DEF.GHI.XY8
```